# It is possible to make a non-malicious keylogger in Flutter for IOS and Android?

Tags: flutter

it is possible to make a non-malicious keylogger in Flutter that works in IOS and Android?

The app will be for kids supervision and will be visible in the notification area.

Answer (score 0):

Keyloger needs access privileges through the device's operating system,but  Flutter apps cannot have such access privileges.So it is no possible to make keyloggers with Flutter.

Comment: I think that if you ask for an accessibility authorization you can access the whole os even if you do not have a privileged access (admin, root, etc).
Did'n try but make sense, like antivirus applications for example that need to access more or less everything.

Answer (score -1):

you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_keyboard to prevent malicious keyloggers.